# MVC Razor Code Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
<tbody class="searchable">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Account.AccountName != "xyz")
            <tr class="danger">
        else
            <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

The compiler doesn't like the if statement where I'm trying to create a row tag dynamically. The error I'm getting says the @foreach block is missing a close '}'. My guess is that the 'if' statement is being misinterpreted. Can someone suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just avoid the if, and do something like:

```
<tr class='@(item.Account.AccountName != "xyz" ? "danger" : "")'>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
    </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
  </td>
</tr>
```